# Laravel why $request->user() relationship don't work properly?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have few $request->user->load() relationships :

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:api','request.log'])->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()->load('accesses');
});
Route::get('settings', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()->load('settings');
});
Route::get('logs', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()->load('logs');
});
```

But for some reason, first relationship('accesses') don't work properly. I call this route right after user login to get user info and his accesses to different site modules. It returns user info correctly, but accesses is always null. Also, $this->id don't work inside model for this relation, while works for others. How can I fix it?

Relationship with problem

```php
public function accesses()
{
    if (!($this->hasOne(UserAccesses::class)->exists())) { 
        $accesses = new UserAccesses();
        $accesses->user_id = Auth::id(); // $this->id don't work for some reason
        $accesses->disk = true;
        $accesses->mail = true;
        $accesses->calendar = true;
        $accesses->photos = true;
        $accesses->contacts = true;
        $accesses->save();
    }

    return $this->hasOne(UserAccesses::class);
}
```

almost the same relationship that works ok

```php
public function settings()
{
    if (!($this->hasOne(UserSettings::class)->exists())) {
        $settings = new UserSettings();
        $settings->user_id = $this->id;
        $settings->backup_password = '';
        $settings->backup_email = '';
        $settings->codeword = '';
        $settings->security_notifications = 0;
        $settings->password_changed_at = null;
        $settings->two_step_authentication = 0;
        $settings->save();
    }

    return $this->hasOne(UserSettings::class);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this `$accesses->user_id = Auth::user()->id;`

Comment: @A.ANoman I need to use $this->id because I call this relationship not only for logged user